# Typescript slow response/intellisense with MUI

Tags: typescript, material-ui

To import something using code actions `ctrl`+`.` it takes forever for typescript to figure out this import exists. I have to close code actions window and reopen it several times until I see the import I need.

[image: First time i summon code actions there's no import]

[image: After several attempts of closing and reopening code actions it finally appears]

Typescript reacts to code changes very slow, too. Once I fix an error, it takes about 15-30 seconds for errors to disappear.

I tried different clients: vscodium, code-oss and proprietary vscode by microsoft (the last in the list works best for some reason) but all have this same problem.

I have somewhat decent hardware: ryzen 5 4600h and 16gb ram, OS is running on ssd.

I do use default imports

```js
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
```

rather than named imports

```js
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
```

I don't have any extra config in `settings.json` or heavy extensions.

But still I'm having very poor experience with material-ui+typescript. Only with material-ui+typescript. Never experienced anything similar with other UI libraries.

Any advices?

Comment: is this the issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34801 ?

Comment: yeah it's. thanks for info. applied a few optimization tips and now it's a little bit better.